# Getting data from zigbee to mqtt to influxdb for use in Grafana

Tags: influxdb

I want to make `grafana` dashboards for my `zigbee` sensors.
Apparently the approach is to use `zigbee2mqtt` to get the `zigbee` data into `mqtt` and then something called `telegraf` to put the `mqtt` data into `influxdb` and then point `grafana` at `influxdb`?

I've got `zigbee2mqtt` running and can see my data, for example using

```
# mosquitto_sub mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 1883 -t zigbee2mqtt/Home/# -F "%I %t %p"
```

So next I installed `influxdb`

```
npm install influxdb influx-client
```

And configured it to get my mqtt data by appending to `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` the following:

```
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]
  topics = [
    "zigbee2mqtt/Home/#",
  ]
```

Unsurprisingly, it doesn't work.
Why?
(It's suspicipious that we don't say where in `influxdb` to put the mqtt data.)

Will Grafana be able to use the JSON data from the sensors, or do the actual temperature values have to be somehow extracted from the JSON and sent in some special format to influxdb?

**Update**

Apparently `telegraph` needs to be installed separately and has config in `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf`

```
# wget https://dl.influxdata.com/telegraf/releases/telegraf_1.21.4-1_amd64.deb
# dpkg -i telegraf_1.21.4-1_amd64.deb
# telegraf --sample-config > telegraf.conf
# systemctl start telegraf
```

The packages for `influxdb` 2 are not upgrades to the existing packages; they're different:

```
# apt-get purge influxdb influxdb-client
# apt-get install influxdb2 influxdb2-client
# systemctl unmask influxdb
# systemctl start influxdb
```

and this makes a website appear at `localhost:8086`. In the website I made a new *bucket* called `zigbee` and copied the value of an API token. Then in `telegraf.config`:

```
  [[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
    servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]
    topics = [
      "zigbee2mqtt/Home/+/Temp",
    ]
    data_format = "json_v2"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]
      measurement_name = "temperature"
      [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.topic_parsing]]
        topic = "_/_/room/_"
      [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
        path = "temperature"
        type = "float"

  [[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
    servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]
    topics = [
      "zigbee2mqtt/Home/+/Radiator",
    ]
    data_format = "json_v2"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]
      measurement_name = "temperature"
      [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.topic_parsing]]
        topic = "_/_/room/_"
      [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
        path = "local_temperature"
        type = "float"
        rename = "temperature"

[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
  token = "token"
  organization = "mini31"
  bucket = "zigbee"
```

Seeing some data in the InfluxDB website but it's nonsense which suggest that the JSON parsing configuration needs work.

Comment: Your .conf file is meant for telegraf instead of influxdb, right? check here for the params to use, https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/mqtt_consumer

Comment: That _is_ what I put into `etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf`. Are you saying there's a _different_ file for `telegraf`?
I've been fucking around with `influxdb2` and now it's all broken anyway.

Comment: the flow shall be `zigbee -> mqtt -> telegraf -> influxdb -> grafana`, you kind of missing `telegraf` part.